# open other android applications

Tags: android

Currently, I have three applications, named A, B and C (just for example).

A will pass the file Uri to B using intent, after that, B will choose one of the proper application, C, to open the file.

For example, A pass a image uri to B, and B finds out A pass a image uri, so B will choose gallery( its C ) to open the file and show on the screen.

However, when I press "back" button and the screen will back to application from C to B, than A.

So, my problem is what can I do to hide the application B? my mean is when I press "back" button in application C and the screen will back to A directly, instead of B?

Comment: you can call finish() after calling C in B

Comment: It is one of solution; however, I am looking for other solutions. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

create the onBackPressed() method in application c and restart the A intent/activity.
i hope its what u need.

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();       
            Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, however, I cannot edit the code in some programs, such as gallery or music! At the same time, I cannot edit the A, too. The only things I can handle is application B.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android:noHistory=true
```

in the manifest of Application(activity in the application) B.. it  removes the activity from the activity stack and finishes (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and is no longer visible on screen